# Use AWS Route53 for Disaster Recovery - Route53 failed to redirect users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I deployed a web application in AWS. This is how I setup the environment....
I have Route53 Latency-Based Routing to serve web requests to users from the region closest to the user.
To provide disaster recovery, I have weighted record sets associated with two web servers in separate AZs per region.

Last night I disabled all web servers in one of the regions to test Disaster Recovery. Route 53 does not automatically direct all users to the other region. What's not right? I think its the configuration. What should I check?

Comment: Do you have the RRs associated with Route 53 health checks?  Did they fail as expected?  Did you set up your RRs with short TTLs?  Did you test what Route 53 was returning, using `dig`?

Answer (score 2):

Did you setup health checks and failover. Route 53 will failover only if you set it up - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html